# Viewing PDF inside the browser with Foxit Reader

Tags: windows-7, foxit-reader

Are the two options below during the installation the same?

[image]

[image]

I use Foxit Reader 7 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Are the two options below during the installation the same?**

No.

The first one **installs** the plugin (which is required to use Foxit to render PDFs inside the browser).

The second one says **use** the plugin to to render PDFs **inside** the browser instead of opening a separate Foxit application to render PDFs.